# Compact desk for daw and music composition?

Tags: home-studio, daw

We're finding that the desk for our daw, plus the keyboard to the side of it (Yamaha P-140) is getting to be a bit much for our space. Ideally we'd like the the computer and keyboard to share the same space so that the user doesn't have to turn his/her head to look at the screens when playing the keyboard.

Are there solutions for this? If so what are people preferred?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of three different configurations.  Which one you settle on will depend on how often you use the Yamaha and how you use it.  Spend a little time searching Google's image search to find some ideas.

1. **Keyboard and mouse in front of the Yamaha on the same surface.**
   This is a simple and common configuration.  It works good if the Yamaha is only lightly used.  A wireless keyboard and mouse are very useful in this setup.  [Here's](http://www.liljendal.dk/music/studio.htm) an example.
2. **Keyboard and mouse in a drawer under the Yamaha.**
   This is a good one if you use the Yamaha a lot.  You'll probably have to compromise on the height so that the Yamaha isn't too high to play on and the keyboard/mouse aren't too low to use comfortably.  [Here's](http://www.markmillermusic.org/blog/my-studio/) an example of this one.
3. **Keyboard and mouse beside the Yamaha.**
   I would only use this one if neither of the other two work.  It seems a little inconvenient to me, but I figured I'd mention it anyway.